# Manipulating Text Nodes on XML from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

New to programming so this may come off as a simple fix to most. With that said, I'm having trouble manipulating XML nodes through HTML code, below is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. Replace "Belgian Waffle" with "English Muffin" as well as change the price, description, and calories with new values.
2. Now decrease every food item's price by 5 percent through implementation of deleting a node and adding a new node approach.

My functions just aren't manipulating the existing data that was loaded in from the XML file and I'm not too sure how to go about with the second step.

XML File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name id="waffle">Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
   Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
   </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>
    Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>
    Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
    </description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>
    Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns
    </description>
    <calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

HTML File

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="one">
<p id="demo"></p>

 </div>
<form>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Change Item">
</form>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","breakfast.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<div id='one'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("food");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<p>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p><p>");
  document.write("Price: ", x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p><p>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p><p>");
  document.write("Calories: ", x[i].getElementsByTagName("calories")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p></br><p id='two'>");
  } 
document.write("</div>");
  
function replace(xml) {
 var textnode = document.createTextNode("English Muffin");

 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle").childNodes[0];
 item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]).innerHTML;
}
function two(xml) { 
 xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "English Muffin";
}
function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle")[0].childNodes[0];
    txt = x.nodeValue + "<br>";
    x.nodeValue="English Muffin";
    txt += x.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will get you closer, you need to add an event listener to the xmlhttprequest to catch the load event. After the load event fires, you can then do the processing of the XML that you want to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="one">
<p id="demo"></p>

 </div>
<form>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Change Item">
</form>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","breakfast.xml",false);
  // this only sends out the request, it does not get populated with a response
  xmlhttp.send();
  // to get the file contents you need to add event listener for load event
  xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function(evt){

   
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<div id='one'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("food");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
      document.write("<p>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</p><p>");
      document.write("Price: ", x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</p><p>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</p><p>");
      document.write("Calories: ", x[i].getElementsByTagName("calories")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</p></br><p id='two'>");
    } 
      document.write("</div>");
});
function replace(xml) {
 var textnode = document.createTextNode("English Muffin");

 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle").childNodes[0];
 item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]).innerHTML;
}
function two(xml) { 
 xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "English Muffin";
}
function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsById("waffle")[0].childNodes[0];
    txt = x.nodeValue + "<br>";
    x.nodeValue="English Muffin";
    txt += x.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not configuring your `XMLHttpRequest` object properly. You have not set up a "success" callback function and instead, after sending the request, your code immediately attempts to access the result without waiting for the request to process and so there is no return value at that point.

XHR requests are asynchronous and that means that we don't know how long they will take to return. We must set up a callback that can be called whenever that happens.

The general way to set up an XHR is as follows:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","breakfast.xml",false);

// Set up callback functions to handle the outcomes of the request
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
xmlhttp.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);

// Only after the XHR has been completely configured can you send the request    
xmlhttp.send();

// This function will be called when there is a successful
// response from the request.
function transferComplete(evt){
   // Only when this function is called (automatically by the XHR)
   // is it safe to access: xmlhttp.responseXML and only from within
   // this function can you call it (unless you assign it to a higher
   // scoped variable, but that wouldn't be a good idea because outside
   // of this function, you can't be sure that the assignment has taken place.

   // Also, instead of multiple document.write() statements, just
   // populate an existing DOM element with the contents of
   // the response.
}

// This function will be called when there is an error
function transferFailed(evt){
  console.log("Something went wrong!");
}
```

See **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)** for more details on setting up an XMLHttpRequest.

**NOTES:**

- All browsers have natively supported the `XMLHttpRequest` object for
  many years now. Unless you are still supporting IE 8, you can remove
  that entire if statement and just use: `xmlhttp=new
  XMLHttpRequest();`.
- `document.write()` is only used when writing dynamic content to a new
  window. Instead, just modify the content of an existing DOM element.